# React Native Maps renders 2 background layers - blurred effect

Tags: react-native, maps, render, react-native-maps, blurry

I have a React Native application that contains a (react-native-maps) mapview with several different polylines and polygons created from http request data. The problem is that the map renders the background twice as you can see in the attached picture. This second layer is always a bit larger and more out of focus than the actual layer (the polygon/lines match with coordinaates on the clear defined layer). Im wondering how this second background came to be and how to prevent it from rendering.

Kind regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying, that without providing an  you are getting two layers?

Otherwise, when you use a different provider, for a layer and want to hide the layer provided by google,  You should set mapType to "none".

Comment: This did indeed solve my issue, thank you very much. Marked as correct.